# Replace a character squence in java using regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have the following text

"This ball isn?t yours, this one is John?s"

I want to correct this to be

"This ball isn't yours, this one is John's"

How can I do this in Java using Pattern and Matcher?

Comment: Is this a post-mortem fix for a character encoding issue?

Comment: Any reason you want to use a regular expression for this rather than just replacing one character sequence with another?

Comment: How will you avoid `Is this John?s ball?` from turning into `Is this John's ball'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[string.replaceall](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
 String fixed = old.replaceAll("\\?([ts])", "'$1");
```

Here's an [**example**](http://ideone.com/cJEYh)

Comment: Is this John?s ball? -> Is this John's ball'

Comment: @smas, that won't happen because of `([st])`

Comment: I've commented the 1st version of your post. But still replacing '?' to ' is strange to me.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you could use:

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\b?\\b", "'");
```

Then you'll be much less likely to replace legitimate question marks, as @glowcoder mentioned.  However, I think @Philipp is right, and this is really a character-encoding issue.  It looks like your text was supposed to be:

```
"This ball isn’t yours, this one is John’s"
```

If it was encoded as cp-1252 but decoded as ASCII, the curly single-quotes would be replaced with question marks.  If that's the case, you're likely to find other characters, like curly double-quotes (`“ ”`), en-dash (`–`) and em-dash (`—`), that have been munged in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, a regular expression is not needed.

```
String s = "This ball isn?t yours, this one is John?s";
s = s.replace("?","'");
System.out.println(s);
```

prints

```
This ball isn't yours, this one is John's
```